# Integration of 'jonblum:jquery-cropper' in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, meteor, crop

How do I add the JavaScript code in my Meteor application? This is what I want to include:

[image: jquery-cropper]

Here is the code:

```
$('.cropper-example-1 > img').cropper({
    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
    autoCropArea: 0.65,
    strict: false,
    guides: false,
    highlight: false,
    dragCrop: false,
    cropBoxMovable: false,
    cropBoxResizable: false
});
```

Comment: In what context? A template? Your question is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

How to include the [`jonblum:jquery-cropper`](https://github.com/jonblum/meteor-cropper/) package:

1. Run `meteor add jonblum:jquery-cropper`.
2. Run `mkdir public` in your project root.
3. Place the image you want to crop in your `/public` directory.
4. Include the image, for example:

---

```
<template name="lena">
    <div class="cropper-example-lena">
        <img src="/lena.jpg" alt="Lena">
    </div>
</template>
```

5. Implement the [`Template.myTemplate.onRendered`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_onRendered) function and include the [`Cropper`](http://fengyuanchen.github.io/cropper/) code, for instance:

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
    Template.lena.onRendered(function () {
        $('.cropper-example-lena > img').cropper({
            aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
            autoCropArea: 0.65,
            strict: false,
            guides: false,
            highlight: false,
            dragCrop: false,
            cropBoxMovable: false,
            cropBoxResizable: false
        });
    });
}
```

6. Finally, include the template, e.g. `{{> lena}}`.

Result:
[image: lena-jquery-cropper]

Comment: Your great boss . Tell me the good source to learn the Meteor Frame work . Thanks lot !!!!